# wayback_machine_donwloader giving an error trying to download "http://mexiko-lexikon.de" from web archive

Tags: ruby, webarchive

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtuwT.png)

Any idea why I am getting this?

```
Getting snapshot pagesTraceback (most recent call last):
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:23:in `<main>'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:23:in `load'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:72:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:192:in `download_files'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:309:in `file_list_by_timestamp'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:168:in `get_file_list_by_timestamp'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:105:in `get_file_list_curated'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:88:in `get_all_snapshots_to_consider'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader/archive_api.rb:8:in `get_raw_list_from_api'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:377:in `open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this one:

```
wayback_machine_downloader https://www.mexiko-lexikon.de --from 20120624174321
```

Sidenote: change the `http` protocoll to `https`!

Result:

```
Downloading https://www.mexiko-lexikon.de to websites/www.mexiko-lexikon.de/ from Wayback Machine archives.

Getting snapshot pages.. found 32 snaphots to consider.

1 files to download:
http://mexiko-lexikon.de/ -> websites/www.mexiko-lexikon.de/index.html (1/1)

Download completed in 3.46s, saved in websites/www.mexiko-lexikon.de/ (1 files)
```

Comment: Thanks you are a GEM. :D